# How to handle with webdrivers in visual studio code Protractor?

Tags: protractor, visualstudio, jasmine

**I was getting an error**

```
WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot determine loading status from unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level' (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

I updated Visual Studio Code a few days ago. Now I think that it is incompatible with ChromeDriver. I'm using chrome76.

Before updating VS code it was working correctly but now it gives that error. I searched everywhere on net. Some of them telling that I need to upgrade chrome driver etc. Kindly upload complete procedure how to check for software and how to handle that.

Same Program I run on firefox it runs But when it runs on chrome it gives that error

Comment: You mention other answers are saying to upgrade the version of Chromedriver. Have you actually done that? You can find new Chromedrivers here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads.

Comment: yup By installing that manually and by Writing webdriver-manager update command

Comment: So, are you still having errors when running chromedriver after the update?

Comment: Have you updated browser as well ?

Answer (score 1):

What's the most likely cause of this error is a mismatch of Chrome version between Chrome itself - *OP reported (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)* - and the Chromedriver - *(Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174)*. Updating the Chromedriver version to match the Chrome version resolves the error.

Per the Chromedriver history found [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.27/), version 2.27 was released in December 2016 and shouldn't work with Chrome 76, which was released July 2019.

Although the OP is using Protractor with Chromedriver, the naming convention of Chromedriver used to reflect the version of Selenium, in this case, 2.27 would match Selenium 2. Around the time of Chrome 70-73, Chromedriver updated its naming convention to reflect the version of Chrome itself. You can see the history of version name changes [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

`webdriver-manager update`
is the command that will automatically update the Chrome driver But some time is not update Because of slow performance For that i Shutdown my PC, after  few hours it updated Automatically